# Get match-string from route-object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

How can I get the "match"-string again from my request? Given I request a site with /users/1, I can get the current route object in my controller with:

```
Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(request) do |route, matches, param|
 ...
end
```

How can I get my original "route / match" string again, in this example

```
"users/:id"
```

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Comment: Given a string which contains a route, you want to know which entry in the output of `rake routes` it would match?

Comment: do you need to get the path?

Comment: @muistooshort exactly!